# Condense repeated events in the moderator tools

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools

Can this:

> Moderator deletes flag votes, Moderator deletes flag votes, Moderator
>   deletes flag votes, Moderator deletes flag votes, Moderator deletes
>   flag votes, Moderator deletes flag votes, Moderator deletes flag
>   votes, Moderator deletes flag votes, Moderator deletes flag votes,
>   Moderator deletes flag votes, Moderator deletes flag votes, Moderator
>   deletes flag votes, Moderator deletes flag votes, Moderator deletes
>   flag votes, Moderator deletes flag votes, Moderator deletes flag
>   votes, Moderator deletes flag votes, Moderator deletes flag votes,
>   Moderator deletes flag votes, Moderator deletes flag votes, Moderator
>   deletes flag votes, Moderator deletes flag votes, Moderator deletes
>   flag votes, Moderator deletes flag votes, Moderator deletes flag
>   votes, Moderator deletes flag votes, Moderator deletes flag votes,
>   Moderator deletes flag votes, Moderator deletes flag votes, Moderator
>   deletes flag votes, Moderator destroys user, Moderator deletes flag
>   votes, Moderator deletes flag votes, Moderator deletes flag votes,
>   Moderator deletes flag votes, Moderator deletes flag votes, Moderator
>   deletes flag votes, Moderator deletes flag votes, Moderator deletes
>   flag votes, Moderator deletes flag votes, Moderator deletes flag
>   votes, Moderator deletes flag votes, Moderator deletes flag votes,
>   Moderator deletes flag votes, Moderator deletes flag votes, Moderator
>   deletes flag votes, Moderator deletes flag votes, Moderator deletes
>   flag votes, Moderator destroys user, Moderator deletes flag votes

be changed to this?

> Moderator deletes flag votes (x50)

Comment: Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes

Comment: You might want to list the "Moderator destroys user" also in the summary.

Comment: All work and no play makes Robert a dull boy ...

Comment: @waffles "TWSS"

Comment: @Robert - added to my list; I'm out for a few days first, though

Comment: "Moderator destroys user"? I didn't know that some of the ♦s are terminators.

Answer (score 5):

48×Moderator deletes flag votes, 2×Moderator destroys user

<sub>(you'll have to imagine that there is title text in the above, for the additional information for each)</sub>

next deploy